# How to send response through webhook in hangouts chat to the same thread

Tags: webhooks, google-hangouts

I am able to send messages to chat room through webhooks by app script,But how can i send reply to that messages.It's being as a one way chat.How can i able to make that as a flow of conversation through webhooks.

Comment: This was what worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372950/posting-a-webhook-to-existing-thread

Answer (score 9):

You can supply a `threadKey` as query parameter. You can generate this key yourself. Messages with the same `threadKey` are grouped together.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/<space>/messages?key=<key>\&token=<token>\&threadKey=this-thread-rocks --data '{"text": "hi there"}'
```

See https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create for documentation.