# How do you respond to a thread in Google Chat from an incoming webhook?

Tags: google-chat

There's a thread that my webhook has previously created that it wants to reply to.  Is this possible using a webhook?  It seems to be possible with a bot, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58657945/3832377

But I can't find any documentation on doing it from a webhook.  As I've created the original message in the thread, I can guarentee a consistent threadId.

I tried to send a body that looked like:

```
{
  "cards": [/* a card */]
  "thread": { "name": "some_thread_name" }
}
```

But received a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create

States you have to add the `threadKey` as a query parameter, not in the request body.

Comment: Is this supposed to work for webhooks too? The payload seems to be the same as described in the API above, but adding {'thread': {'threadKey': 'spaces/AAAAxXDxBT5/threads/WnQyxiB_Yig'}} still creates a new thread. I have taken the threadKey from a previous response from `thread.name`.

Comment: I have also tried adding `{"thread": {"name": "paces/AAAAxXDxBT5/threads/WnQyxiB_Yig"}}` which did not work either. It creates a new message instead of replying in-thread.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a long time trying to figure this out, and finally found the answer.

The documentation from Google doesn't cover this question in a way that makes sense, and I just had to find it via trial and error.

To add your chat as a reply using the webhook, you copy the webhook URL, and then append this: `&threadKey=TheNameOfTheThreadIllCallThisOneBob` An example of what a full webhook for this might look like is this:

```
https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAPeRudTM/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=Qqd9NHOkp-EU3XV7ZM9TguW65Nz1p_qUwoijbWYxGS4%3D&threadKey=TheNameOfTheThreadIllCallThisOneBob
```

If the thread doesn't already exist, it will create a new thread, and then send chats to that thread as a reply in the future.

Comment: I'm doing this to send a message via GoogleAppScript and it isn't working. It sends all the messages as new message. Has anything changed recently ?

Comment: This is still working for me. You appended the threadkey at the end of the webhook URI?

Comment: Yep, I did append it. It posted same message in but outside thread. On that note, are you doing it for a DM/group or GSpace ?

Comment: Dm/group I've never touched a gspace before

Answer (score 0):

1. Send a message to gchat, it returns sth. like this:

```
{
    'argumentText': 'hello!',
    [..]
    'thread': {
        'name': 'spaces/AAAA1sHo4Hs/threads/guFWnUZ1r-13',
        'retentionSettings': {'state': 'PERMANENT'}
    }
}
```

2. Add the value of "thread.name" to your "reply-to" message, e.g.:

```
payload = {
    "text": "hello inline!",
    "thread": {
        "name": "spaces/AAAA1sHo4Hs/threads/guFWnUZ1r-13",
    }
}
```

3. Make sure to add the "messageReplyOption" [1] parameter to your URL!

```
url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAA1sHo4Hs/messages?key=<auth key>&token=<auth token>&messageReplyOption=REPLY_MESSAGE_FALLBACK_TO_NEW_THREAD'
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create#MessageReplyOption